# Explanation for cryptic double pointer assignment

Tags: c, pointers

I'm reading the c code:

```
 void **alignedData = (void **)(((size_t)temp + aligned - 1)&-aligned);
```

I do not known the means, especially the `&-` part.

Can anyone explain it?

Thanks!

Comment: Two separate operators, bitwise AND `&` and unary negation `-`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using this, `aligned` should be an unsigned type (or the C implementation should be using two’s complement) and have a value that is a power of two. Then this code calculates an amount of memory to be allocated:

- `(size_t) temp` converts `temp` to the unsigned type `size_t`, which is suitable for working with sizes. This will be a number of bytes to be allocated.
- `(size_t) temp + aligned - 1` adds enough bytes to guarantee a multiple of `aligned` falls somewhere between the numbers `temp` and `temp + aligned - 1`, inclusive. For example, if `temp` is 37 and `aligned` is 8, then between 37 and 44 (37+8−1), there is a multiple of 8 (40).
- `-aligned` makes a bit mask with 1 in each bit position that is a multiple of `aligned` and 0 in the lower bits. For example, if `aligned` is 8, then the bits that represent `-aligned` are 111…111000, because the 000 bits at the end represent values of 1, 2, and 4, while the other bits represent values of 8, 16, 32, and so on.
- The `&` (bitwise AND) of `(size_t) temp + aligned - 1` with `-aligned` then clears the low bits, leaving only bits that are multiples of `aligned`. Thus, it produces the multiple of `aligned` that is in the interval. For example, with the values of 37 and 8 mentioned before, `((size_t) temp + aligned - 1) & -aligned` produces 40.

Thus, this expression produces the value of `temp` rounded up to the next multiple of `aligned`. It says “Calculate the number of bytes we need to allocate that is at least `temp` bytes and is a multiple of `aligned`.”

After this, the code converts this number to the type `void **` and uses it to initialize `void **alignedData`. That is bad C code. There is generally no good reason for it. A number of bytes like this should not be used as any kind of pointer. The code may be attempting to “smuggle” this value through a data type it is compelled to use by some other software, but there is likely a better way to do it, such as by allocating memory to hold the value and supplying a pointer to that memory instead of trying to convert the value directly. Finding a better solution requires knowing more context of the code.